# What is the policy for permissions on /proc/<PID>/environ?

Tags: linux, permissions, process, proc

I see, that usual user process gets user-readable permissions:

```
-r-------- 1 1000 1000 0 Nov 19 13:51 /proc/9083/environ
```

but f.ex. SCREEN daemon gets `root` ownership:

```
-r-------- 1 root root 0 Nov 19 13:47 /proc/9167/environ
```

Though, 9167 is also user UID:

```
# ps axnu|grep 9167
    1000  9167  0.0  0.0  23488  2008 ?   Ss   13:47   0:00 SCREEN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On most systems, `/usr/bin/screen` is installed with the *setuid* bit for root, meaning it will first start with effective UID 0, and only later drop privileges (returning to your normal UID).

*(This is used for implementing the "session sharing" feature, as your Screen wouldn't be allowed to connect to other users' Screen sockets otherwise.)*

But, since privileged processes could potentially keep sensitive information in memory, the kernel gives them special protection – even if they drop all privileges and switch to your UID, you still cannot send them signals, attach a debugger, or create core dumps.

The "no core dumps" option, also known as the `fs.suid_dumpable` sysctl setting, is what causes Screen's `/proc` files to be permanently owned by root regardless of its effective UID.